# Email Responsiveness: Media Queries Trouble Shooting (specific iPhone targeting issue)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, html-email

I'm trying to improve the responsiveness of our emails, but seem to be running into some issues with differentiating the styling for iPhone 4,5,6,6+ from something like Android 2.3 or an iPhone 3. Specifically I want certain width requirements to be based on what type of phone you're opening the email on (smaller width for older phones larger for newer).

The specific issue I'm having is that it appears that the bottom media query, the one intended just for Android 2.3/iPhone3/Other older phones, is being used by all devices. Seems like it's probably some sort of inheritance issue but I can't seem to figure out what exactly is happening.

Here are the different media query targeting rules I'm using and in the order they're in my code:

**INTENDED FOR IPHONE 6+**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 736px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 3) and (device-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {...}
```

**INTENDED FOR IPHONE 6**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 667/375) {...}
```

**INTENDED FOR TABLETS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {...}
```

**INTENDED FOR IPHONE 5**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {...}
```

**INTENDED FOR IPHONE 4/S**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {...}
```

**INTENDED FOR ANDROID 2.3, IPHONE 3 AND ANYTHING ELSE**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {...}
```

Unfortunately it appears the styling being passed to the bottom query is being used by all devices. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you passed it through a validator to make sure that all of your code is closed properly?
http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Comment: You should note that most email clients are using extremely outdated and/or basic renderers, which ignores or are unable to parse many CSS rules that we see as commonplace on the web today. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3564/applying-fluid-layouts-to-html-email-design/

Comment: Did you try moving the Android 2.3, iPhone 3, etc rule around (eg. up)?

Comment: @ether Yes I have tried passing through a validator - everything is all closed

Comment: @terry Yes I'm aware but I'm pretty sure everything I'm using should be supported

Comment: @jabbink I did indeed - no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {...}
```

This last rule will apply to ALL screens with max-width: 480px so it will override the above 2 rules INTENDED FOR IPHONE 4/S and INTENDED FOR IPHONE 5 which target the same screen size.

Try using the "not" operator in your media queries for a more specific targeting.
Examples here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `min-width` to those media queries. ex-

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
     body{font-size:14px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */ @
    media only screen
    and(min - device - width: 320 px)
    and(max - device - width: 480 px)
    and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 2 / 3) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }

```
/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 320 px)
and(max - device - width: 568 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 40 / 71) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 375 px)
and(max - device - width: 667 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 667 / 375) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }


/* iPhone 6 plus in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 414 px)
and(max - device - width: 736 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 3) and(device - aspect - ratio: 16 / 9) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```